# Nextjs / Typescript - Mapping through images throws error 'missing required src property'

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

**Problem:**
When I map through an array of objects, e.g. the string entries are displayed correctly. The images in the Image Component are not loaded dynamically in the src.

The images are imported in the constants.js file and exported via the 'trustedClients' (array of objects).

**Error:**

```
Image is missing required "src" property
```

**Expected result:** Mapping through all objects of the trustedClients Array and return all values. Set the image as dynamic src for the Image component.

**Files:**

```
// constants.js file 
// with image import and array export
import {
    example1Image,
    example2Image,
    example3Image,
} from '../assets';

export const trustedClients = [
    {
        index: 'example1',
        name: 'Example One',
        image: example1Image,
    },
    {
        index: 'example2',
        name: 'Example Two',
        image: example2Image,
    },
    {
        index: 'example3',
        name: 'Example Three',
        image: example3Image,
    },
];
```

```
// component file with mapping
// code is a simpliefied version without the styling
import Image from 'next/image';
import { trustedClients } from '../constants';

const Trusted = () => (
        <div>
            {trustedClients.map((client) => {
                return (
                    <div key={client.index}>
                        <div>
                            <Image
                                src={client.image}
                                alt='client'
                                width='48px'
                                height='48px'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p>{client.name}</p>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
);

export default Trusted;
```

**Question:**
What is the correct use case to get the mapping through the images working and set it as the src of the Image component.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(client.image)`?

Comment: @johannchopin: I get "undefined"

Comment: So there is a problem with your assets import. Please add in the question how you import your images in `../assets`.

Comment: @johannchopin
Thank you so much for the help. I found the problem! 
In the assets folder I have an index.js file.
In this file I import all images and export it.

The problem was:

I exported it like:
```export images = {...}```

But the export should be
```export {...}```

Comment: Nice then maybe add it as the answer so that the topic is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The export of images in the assets-folder was not correct.

I exported it like:
`export images = {...}`

But the correct export should be
`export {...}`